# Navigation Layout Takes over Main Activity Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer into my app, but for some reason whenever I add the nav drawer fragment in my `main_activity` xml layout, it covers up/replaces the content of my main activity. When I remove the fragment, my recyclerview properly appears again.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout    
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_actionbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_image_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_order_hub"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_order_hub_trans"
        android:layout_above="@+id/space2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/space2"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        android:id="@+id/space2" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_button_diameter"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/space" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.android.expresso.expresso.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
<!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
   android:background="#cccc"
   tools:context="com.android.expresso.expresso.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

And this is what happens when I run the app. *Note: the `Matthew Steinhardt` and `Matthew.steinhardt@gmail.com` is the text that's supposed to only show up when the navigation drawer is opened, but for some reason it's also showing up in my main activity.*

***Left*** - Image of the problem, ***Right***, Image of the nav drawer:

[image] [image]

If you need any more info, lemme know, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
   android:layout_width="240dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
   android:background="#cccc"
   tools:context="com.android.expresso.expresso.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this will Help you.

Comment: didn't seem to help :(